# Discord.js bot not starting after refreshing slash commands, but no errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js, replit

I'm using the example code from https://discord.js.org and my bot won't start. Here's my code with the token/id changed

```js
const { REST, Routes, Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
    {
        name: 'ping',
        description: 'Replies with Pong!',
    },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(process.env.BOT_ID), { body: commands });
    
        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

And here's the console:
[image]

(note that I'm using replit)
I've also tried removing the slash command code, but it still doesn't start the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Replit May have a issue with the discord api.
Please type `kill 1` in your replit shell.
I hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me for some reason. The only thing appeared in the console is the client_id, “Started refreshing application (/) commands.” and “Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.”

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Don't write a new question in the answer box. Instead, please wait for someone to answer this question. If you have enough reputation, you can [place a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to attract more attention to this question. If you have a new and separate question, use the "[Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" button.